# Redis Bulk data upload ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command

Tags: r, linux, bash, redis

I'm a redis noob, and I'm struggling to simply get my data into the database.  I have about 900,000 records and I constructed a pipeline .txt file in R that outputs the following:

```
    SET "120705373" "Wilshire;01/30/2012;THEFT OF IDENTITY;Invest Cont;34.0441;-118.3382;Other"
    SET "120705394" "Wilshire;01/30/2012;BATTERY ;Adult Other;34.0472;-118.3574;Assault"
    SET "120705395" "Wilshire;01/30/2012;BATTERY ;Adult Other;34.0472;-118.3574;Assault"
    ...etc
```

Now when I run the file in bash:

```
    cat /mnt/c/Users/filename.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

I get "ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command. I have tried parsing this file in as many ways as possible and I continue to hit this brick wall. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved: The issue was adding underscores into the fields (e.g. Wilshire;01/30/2012;THEFT_OF_IDENTITY;Invest_Cont;34.0441;-118.3382;Other)

Answer (score 1):

The --pipe option is meant to be used for mass insertion. You need to feed redis-cli --pipe with data encoded with the Redis protocol, not just plain text Redis commands.

See http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert for more explanation.